# JavaScript revealing module pattern re-factoring advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, refactoring

I am using the revealing module pattern with JavaScript quite alot to organise my code in my current project but am wondering if i could use it in a better way as i seem to be creating lots of private methods and then calling them in a linear fashion i.e. when one method has performed its operation then call another and then another and so on.

The code works but would like to see if it could work better, more efficiently or with less code to achieve the same result.

An example module would be below where we need to:

1. Bind a click event to a tab
2. set some meta data values
3. Call 3rd party tracking functions
4. Reset the meta data to its original value

   ```
   icisSite.tabPageView = function($){

       var $tabs = $('.tbc .tbc-tabs > div'),
           pageName = $('meta[name=gwa_pageName]'),
           sec3 = $('meta[name=gwa_siteSection3]'),
           sec4 = $('meta[name=gwa_siteSection4]'),
           pageNameLen = pageName.length,
           sec3Len = sec3.length,
           sec4Len = sec4.length,
           txt,
           pNameContent,
           pNameConstruct,
           section,
           metaContent,
           metaConstruct;

       function init() {   
           bindClickHandlerToTabs();
       };  

       function bindClickHandlerToTabs() {
           if (pageNameLen !== 0 && (sec3Len !== 0 || sec4Len !== 0)){
               $tabs.bind('click', updateMetaData(){
                   txt = $(this).find('span').text(),
                   txt = ' | ' + txt;
                   updateMetaData();
               }); 
           } else {
               return false;
           }           
       };  

       function updateMetaData(){
           pNameContent = pageName.attr('content'),
           pNameConstruct = pNameContent + txt;
           if (sec3Len !== 0 && sec4Len !== 0){
               section = 'gwa_siteSection4',
               metaContent = sec4.attr('content'),
               metaConstruct = metaContent + txt;
           } else {
               section = 'gwa_siteSection3'
               metaContent = sec3.attr('content'),
               metaConstruct = metaContent + txt;
           }   
           return callGWATrackingFucntions();  
       };

       function callGWATrackingFucntions() {
           gwa_SetMetaValue(section, metaConstruct); 
           gwa_trackPageView(pNameConstruct);
           return resetMetaData();
       };

       function resetMetaData() { 
           pageName.attr('content', pNameContent);
           $('meta').each(function(index){
               var name = $(this).attr('name');
               if (section === name){
                   $(this).attr('content', metaContent);   
               }
           });     
       };

       return {
           init: init  
       };

   }(jQuery);

   icisSite.tabPageView.init();
   ```

Comment: The first seven words say it all.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating functions that are only called once, you need to ask why they are functions and not just sequential code. Perhaps it's for extensibility or modularity. The extra function call is not particularly important.

You can greatly improve efficiency (though probably not noticeably) by changing the multiple function calls inherent in things like:

```
$(this).attr('content', metaContent);
```

with direct property access:

```
this.content = metaContent;
```

unless your intention is to modify the HTML content attribute (which is unlikely) rather than the DOM property (I have no idea which one the *attr* method will actually change in this case).

jQuery is about to make some big changes to the much maligned *attr* method, it's always been a good idea to not use it unless you really needed to (which was almost never).